# CUDA histogram2d not working

Tags: python, numpy, cuda, pycuda, histogram2d

Due to a seeming lack of a decent 2D histogram for CUDA (that I can find... pointers welcome), I'm trying to implement it myself with pyCUDA.

Here's what the histogram should look like (using Numpy):

[image: Numpy Histogram]

Here's what I've got so far:

```
code = '''
__global__ void histogram2d(const float *in_x, const float *in_y, const float *in_w, float *out) {{
    int start = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    float *block_out = &out[{xres} * {yres} * {num_chans} * blockIdx.x];

    for(int i = 0; i < {length}; i++) {{
        float x = in_x[start + i];
        float y = in_y[start + i];
        int w_idx = (start + i) * {num_chans};

        int xbin = (int) (((x - {xmin}) / {xptp}) * {xres});
        int ybin = (int) (((y - {ymin}) / {yptp}) * {yres});

        if (0 <= xbin && xbin < {xres} && 0 <= ybin && ybin < {yres}) {{
            for(int c = 0; c < {num_chans}; c++) {{
                atomicAdd(&block_out[(ybin * {xres} + xbin) * {num_chans} + c], in_w[w_idx + c]);
            }}
        }}
    }}
}}
'''.format(**args)

------

__global__ void histogram2d(const float *in_x, const float *in_y, const float *in_w, float *out) {
    int start = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    float *block_out = &out[50 * 50 * 4 * blockIdx.x];

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        float x = in_x[start + i];
        float y = in_y[start + i];
        int w_idx = (start + i) * 4;

        int xbin = (int) (((x - -10.0) / 20.0) * 50);
        int ybin = (int) (((y - -10.0) / 20.0) * 50);

        if (0 <= xbin && xbin < 50 && 0 <= ybin && ybin < 50) {
            for(int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
                atomicAdd(&block_out[(ybin * 50 + xbin) * 4 + c], in_w[w_idx + c]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: CUDA histogram]

There seems to be a problem with the indexing, but I haven't done much pure CUDA before, so I can't tell what it is. Here's what I think the equivalent python would be:

```
def slow_hist(in_x, in_y, in_w, out, blockx, blockdimx, threadx):
    start = blockx * blockdimx + threadx

    block_out_addr = args['xres'] * args['yres'], args['num_chans'] * blockx

    for i in range(args['length']):
        x = in_x[start + i]
        y = in_y[start + i]
        w_idx = (start + i) * args['num_chans']

        xbin = int(((x - args['xmin']) / args['xptp']) * args['xres'])
        ybin = int(((y - args['ymin']) / args['yptp']) * args['yres'])

        if 0 <= xbin < args['xres'] and 0 <= ybin < args['yres']:
            for c in range(args['num_chans']):
                out[(ybin * args['xres'] + xbin) * args['num_chans'] + c] += in_w[w_idx + c]
```

[image: Pure-python histogram]

All the code is viewable, including these images, [at the Github page of this notebook](https://github.com/scnerd/flames/blob/master/flames.ipynb) (this cell is at the bottom).

What am I doing wrong in this CUDA code? I've tried lots of little tweaks (striding the atomicAdd address by 1, 4, 8, 16, transposing outputs, etc.), but it seems like I'm missing something subtle, probably in how the pointer arithmetic is working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: for n samples, in_x and in_y have shapes (n,), and in_w has shape(n,4). out has shape(num_blocks, yres, xres, 4). My goal was to allocate enough space for each CUDA block to have its own (yres, xres, 4) region to write to (so the atomic add's don't block each other), then I sum over axis 0 to get the final histogram

Answer (score 1):

The array being allocated for the output array for the CUDA section used Numpy's default float64 instead of float32, so memory was twice as large as expected. Here's the new histogram output:

[image: New CUDA histogram]

I'd still greatly appreciate comments or answers that help explain why these histograms are all so different from each other.